# Electron vite child process script is not transpiling

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, vite

I'm building an Electron app and I need some background computations done using a child_process (fork).

I'm using the following technologies :

Electron
Vite
TypeScript

I've created a simple script but TS is not transpiling it. I'm assuming since this code isn't directly used.

How would you go about including a child process in an Electron app with a script written in TS? Since this would need to be packaged.

How I'm calling it :

```
const scriptPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'utils', 'dupeScript.ts');
```

Here's my folder structure :

```
└── MY_APP
    └── .editorconfig
    └── .gitignore
    └── .prettierignore
    └── .prettierrc.yaml
    └── dev-app-update.yml
    └── electron-builder.yml
    └── electron.vite.config.ts
    └── package-lock.json
    └── package.json
    └── postcss.config.js
    └── README.md
    └── src
        └── main
            └── electron_constants.ts
            └── handlers
                └── another-file.ts <--- Calls the script
            └── index.ts
            └── types
                └── util.types.ts
            └── utils
                └── childProcesses.ts <-- This file spawns the process 
                └── dupeScript.ts   <-- This is the script file
        └── preload
            └── index.d.ts
            └── index.ts
        └── renderer
            └── ...
        └── shared
            └── constants.ts
        └── types
            └── index.d.ts
    └── tailwind.config.js
    └── tsconfig.json
    └── tsconfig.node.json
    └── tsconfig.web.json
```

This is what Vite/TS puts out

```
└── out
    └── main
        └── index.js
    └── preload
        └── index.js
```

My tsconfig.json

```
{
    "files": ["./src/shared/constants.ts"],
    "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }, { "path": "./tsconfig.web.json" }]
}
```

tsconfig.node.json

```
{
    "extends": "@electron-toolkit/tsconfig/tsconfig.node.json",
    "include": ["electron.vite.config.*", "src/main/**/*", "src/preload/**/*", "src/types"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "types": ["electron-vite/node"]
    }
}
```

tsconfig.web.json

```
{
  "extends": "@electron-toolkit/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": [
    "src/renderer/src/env.d.ts",
    "src/renderer/src/**/*",
    "src/renderer/src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/preload/*.d.ts",
    "src/types"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    // "composite": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@renderer/*": ["src/renderer/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```